# Vue breadcrumbs cannot find meta

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to make dynamic breadcrumbs but it cannot get meta of my routes:

#### Error

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta'
>   of undefined"

#### Code

`route.js`

```
// ADMIN ROUTES
{
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'dashboard',
    component: Dashboard,
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        layout: 'admin',
        name: 'dashboard',
        breadCrumb: 'Dashboard' //here
    }
},
{
    path: '/dashboard/products',
    name: 'adminProducts',
    component: AdminProducts,
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        layout: 'admin',
        breadCrumb: 'Products' //here
    }
},
// and so on...
```

`Admin.vue (layout of my admin dashboard)`

```
<script>
    import FooterBar from './footerBar.vue';
    import navBar from './navBar.vue';
    import adminAside from './adminAside.vue';
    export default {
        name: 'admin',
        data(){
            return {
                site_name: process.env.MIX_APP_NAME
            }
        },
        components: {
           FooterBar,
           navBar,
           adminAside
        },
        computed: {
            crumbs: function() {
                let pathArray = this.$route.path.split("/")
                pathArray.shift()
                let breadcrumbs = pathArray.reduce((breadcrumbArray, path, idx) => {
                    breadcrumbArray.push({
                    path: path,
                    to: breadcrumbArray[idx - 1]
                        ? "/" + breadcrumbArray[idx - 1].path + "/" + path
                        : "/" + path,
                    text: this.$route.matched[idx].meta.breadCrumb || path,
                    });
                    return breadcrumbArray;
                }, [])
                return breadcrumbs;
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

`html`

```
<el-breadcrumb v-for="(item, i) in crumbs" :key="i" separator-class="el-icon-arrow-right">
  <el-breadcrumb-item :to="item.path">{{ item.name }}</el-breadcrumb-item>
</el-breadcrumb>
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

The error came from this line.

```
text: this.$route.matched[idx].meta.breadCrumb || path,
```

It's because you are accessing an index for `matched route` where that index is not available on the array. It seems that the matched route contain only one element and your targeting the index of 1 upon iterating your pathArray.

Or should I say, you're targeting the index in matched route where it does not exists.

That's why vue returned this warning.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined"
```

Please check your `matched route` if it contain elements equal to the length of `pathArray`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207082/discussion-on-answer-by-qonvex620-vue-breadcrumbs-cannot-find-meta).